# Cross Region Replication AWS Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

After doing some research, elastic has built in remote replication. Below is an example of the command for setting up replication to another elastic instance:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.remote.leader.seeds": ["x.xxx.xx.xx:xxxx"]
  }
}
```

At the time of this post, the latest AWS Elasticsearch version is 7.9. Can you set up remote replication within AWS Elasticsearch? If not, are there any alternatives to have replication across regions?

Comment: Cross-Cluster Replication is a feature available in the Elasticsearch default distribution with a subscription for platinum features. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/xpack-ccr.html and https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions#scalability-&-resiliency

Comment: @RussCam that is with the open source elasticsearch. Can you get the platinum version within AWS Elasticsearch?

Comment: @ajohnson10209, did you get a change to workout your requirement?

Comment: I found another way to implement replication via s3 buckets - @PrasanthRajendran

Comment: @ajohnson10209, could you share your approach?

Comment: @PrasanthRajendran I'm planning on submitting an article to medium, but in short, we have a lambda function which is triggered from an s3 event that adds a document to elasticsearch. Since we have that lambda function, I'm able to set up a replicated bucket and create another lambda function which populates another ES domain in another region